# C# WebSocketServer wss:// connection fail

Tags: c#, ssl, browser, websocket

I've written a WebSocket Server which currently works only with ws:// connections.
Tested with http://www.websocket.org/echo.html (on Chrome) and http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/ .

Now I want to also support `wss://` connections (TLS).
I've got it to work with WebSocket4Net but when using the echo test,
javascript immediately throws an exception after `SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer();` is executed in C# code.

It does its TLS negotiation, but Chrome rejects the connection.
SslStream Reads and writes (ServerSide done by AuthenticateAsServer):

```
Read(5, 0, 5) == 5
Read(517, 5, 512) == 512
Write(887, 0, 887)
Read(887, 0, 5) == 5
Read(887, 5, 262) == 262
Read(5, 0, 5) == 5
Read(6, 5, 1) == 1
Read(5, 0, 5) == 5
Read(53, 5, 48) == 48
Write(59, 0, 59)
```

I used the following steps to add the certificate:

```
makecert -sv CA.pvk -r -n "CN=Dev" -a sha256 -len 2048 -sky signature -cy authority CA.cer
makecert -ic CA.cer -iv CA.pvk -n "CN=localhost, CN=127.0.0.1" -a sha256 -len 2048 -sky exchange -sv CA_localhost.pvk -pe CA_localhost.cer
cert2spc CA_localhost.cer CA_localhost.spc
pvkimprt -pfx CA_localhost.spc CA_localhost.pvk //Select export
//Import CA.cer into your Computer store's Trusted Root Certification Authorities (certmgr.msc)
//Import the private key that the server is going to use into the server machine's Personal store.
//This is achieved by importing the .pfx file that you generated earlier.
```

SslStream created by `new SslStream(new NetworkStream(clientSocket), true)`
For AuthenticateAsServer I'm using the "CA_localhost.cer" certificate.

After making sure the certificates are displayed in certmgr.msc I opened 
http://www.websocket.org/echo.html in Chrome and used `wss://localhost:12345` as the address (for which my server is listening) and also checking the checkbox.
After clicking `Connect` I only get:

```
 ERROR: undefined
 DISCONNECTED
```

The javascript console displaying:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:12345/?encoding=text' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

On the serverside after `AuthenticateAsServer` the properties `IsAuthenticated` and `IsEncrypted` are set to true, but immediately after that I receive data of zero length, closing the connection.

I'm assuming I made an error during the certificate creation and/or installation but I don't know what I may have done wrong.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of testing and giving up, I gave it another go:
It turns out (or for me at least it looks like it) that only the last common name is taken to validate against the ws-uri.

Using wss://127.0.0.1:12345 worked.